# Vaadin: window with top-right caption

Tags: java, css, window, vaadin

I defined a window and this is the code:

```
Window w = new Window();
    w.setCaption("caption");
    w.setModal(true);
    w.center();
    w.setDraggable(false);
    w.setClosable(false);
    w.setResizable(false);
    w.setWidth("500px");
    w.setHeight("380px");
    ...
```

And the picture :
 [image: img]

How can i move the caption to the top-right of the window? what CSS should i use?

Comment: @HosienPanahi i have posted answer to your query. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the element to be absolute whom you want to be placed on the top right. But need to keep outer div relative. Providing you a small example in snippet. Here `test` is kept as `relative` and `span` is kept as position `absolute` which is relative to `test`. Here you can place it by providing position. Please check if you find it helpful

```css
.test {
position: relative;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.test span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```